# Parameterized query that returns TEXT column(s) always returns zero for INT columns

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, procedure

Problemt with C# mySQL ODBC
My table

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fbid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`fbname` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`datecreate` datetime NOT NULL,
`ipcreate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`datelogin` datetime NOT NULL,
`iplogin` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`xstatus` int(2) NOT NULL,
`xverstion` int(5) NOT NULL,
`xdata` text NOT NULL,
`xitem` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**My procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `VVVVV_getUserByFbId`(fbid2 varchar(30))
BEGIN
SELECT * from vvvvv_account where vvvvv_account.fbid=fbid2 LIMIT 1;
END
```

fbid2 is parameter (=408301576730032)
in C# code

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(constr);
            OdbcCommand cmd;           
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {

                OpenConnection(connection);

                cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call VVVVV_getUserByFbId(?)}", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fbid2", "408301576730032");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                da.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection(connection);
            }
            return dt;
```

output in C#
`dt.Rows[0]["id"]` always = 0 Not Ok
`dt.Rows[0]["fbname"]` =  "ABC" OK

means I can still get data from database normal. But int column alway = 0, varchar, datetime colume is ok;

**But if I change the procedure to:**

```
BEGIN
    select * from account where account.fbid='408301576730032' LIMIT 1;
END
```

In C# `"{call VVVVV_getUserByFbId()}" -> id field = 3903`

**If no parameter (fbid2) or no text fied (xdata, xitem) -> `id`, xstatus (int fields) return normal. But if an parameter is passed or select xdata -> `id` (int fields) always = 0;**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOWAO.png)

Comment: Problemt with C# mySQL ODBC

Comment: Hey, Can you please describe your question? What I understood was if no parameter return id else return 0. Is that correct?

Comment: 1. My procedure

    BEGIN
    select * from account where account.fbid=fbid2 LIMIT 1;
    END

fbid2 is parameter

Does that mean: In C# if "{call VVVVV_getUserById(?)}" -> id field get value always = 0

2. But if procedure

BEGIN
    select * from account where account.fbid='408301576730032' LIMIT 1;
    END

In C# "{call VVVVV_getUserById()}" -> id field = 3903

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the question better.

Answer (score 2):

You have encountered a verified bug in MySQL Connector/ODBC, reported here:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97191

Since you are using C# you may want to see if MySQL Connector/NET works better for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to convert the returning value to int as follows.

```
int x = System.Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["id"]);
```

The issue might be that MySql int is not mapping to C# int.

Comment: I have convert, but the id value is still zero

Comment: Node: If delete text column (xdata, xitem) in table -> ok. Do not know if the problem is due to these 2 columns?